# pivot convert null to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Below i have create a 2 table  transaction_type and transaction_master then 
transaction_type. transaction_type is contain the credit and debit id's
then  transaction_type is contain the transaction details

```
   transaction_type
   -----------------
   transaction-id|transaction-name
   1             |credit 
   2             |debit

   transaction_master
   -----------
   transaction-id|date_of_transaction|amount
   1             |2016-01-12         |100  
   2             |2015-12-30         |200
   1             |2016-01-05         |300   
   1             |2015-12-04         |500 
   2             |2015-12-12         |50  
   2             |2015-12-25         |1000    
   1             |2016-01-30         |100    

   normal PIVOT output is
   -----------------------
   YEAR|Jan |Feb |mar |Apr |may |Jun |Jul |Aug |Sep |Oct |Nov |Dec

   2015|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|-700

   2016|500 |null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null


   But i want this
   YEAR|Jan |Feb |mar |Apr |may |Jun |Jul |Aug |Sep |Oct |Nov |Dec

   2015|0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   

   2016|500 |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0
```

in above "NULL" and "negative" values should be the "0"

```
   with AA as(select year(d.date_of_transaction),left(date name(month,date_of_transaction),3) as month,sum (case when c. transaction_type like '%c%' then d.Amount else d.Amount*-1)as balance
 from transaction_master d join on transaction_type c c.transaction-id=d.transaction-id group by date_of_transaction) select * from AA pivot(sum(balance) for [month] in (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)) as pvt
```

Comment: Can you show us your query?

Comment: CASE WHEN ISNULL(**col_name**, 0) <= 0 THEN 0
     ELSE **col_name**
END AS alias_name

Comment: with aa as(select year(d.date_of_transaction),left(datename(month,date_of_transaction),3) as month

Comment: Sankar Raj @ where i insert  this line in my queary

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your entire query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) in your final `SELECT` clause:

> [ISNULL] Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

```
;with AA as(
    select 
        year(d.date_of_transaction) AS [year],
        left(datename(month,date_of_transaction),3) as [month],
        sum (case when c. transaction_type like '%c%' then d.Amount else d.Amount*-1 end)as balance
    from 
        transaction_master d join transaction_type c on c.[transaction-id]=d.[transaction-id]
    group by 
        date_of_transaction
 ) 
 select 
    [year],ISNULL(Jan,0) Jan,ISNULL(Feb,0) Feb,ISNULL(Mar,0) Mar,ISNULL(Apr,0) Apr,ISNULL(May,0) May,ISNULL(jun,0) jun,ISNULL(Jul,0) Jul,ISNULL(Aug,0) Aug,ISNULL(Sep,0) Sep,ISNULL(Oct,0) Oct,ISNULL(Nov,0) Nov,ISNULL([Dec],0) [Dec]
 from 
    AA 
    pivot(sum(balance) for [month] in (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)) as pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` and `ISNULL` in following:

```
with aa as(select year(d.date_of_transaction), 
                  case when isnull(left(datename(month,date_of_transaction),3),0) < 1 then 0 else left(datename(month,date_of_transaction),3) end as month
```